# Ruby state_machine gem - test validates_presence_of

Tags: ruby, transition, state-machine

I've added the [state_machine](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine) support to my Post class:

```
state_machine :state, :initial => :draft do

  event :publish do
    transition :draft => :published
  end

  state :draft do
    end
  state :published do
  end 

end
```

In ERB, a new Post indicates that it can be published:

> ```
> >> k=Job.new
> => #<Job id: nil, title: nil>
>
> >> k.can_publish?
> => true
> ```

However, it can't actually be published:

> ```
> >> k.publish!
> StateMachine::InvalidTransition: Cannot transition state via :publish from :draft
> ```

As it turns out, the class' validates_presence_of :title is preventing the change of state.  The save!() method fails because :title is required.  Unfortunately, the InvalidTransition error is a little deceptive.

I'm concerned that this error message will interfere with the View layer's handling of missing fields (:title in my example).  Is there a way to test the validates_presence_of in the can_publish? method?

** edit **

I found the following in the StateMachine::Machine documentation:

> can_park?(requirements = {}) - Checks whether the "park" event can be fired
>   given the current state of the object. This will not run validations in ORM
>   integrations. To check whether an event can fire and passes validations,
>   use event attributes (e.g. state_event) as described in the
>   "Events" documentation of each ORM integration.

Now if I can just determine what 'use event attributes (e.g. state_event) as described in the "Events" documentation of each ORM integration.' means in the scope of ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 1):

The issue appears to be that your object is not passing standard ActiveRecord validation; i.e., if you do:

```
k.valid?
```

you'll find that the object's state is invalid. Once you get the object into a valid state as far as ActiveRecord is concerned then state_machine will allow it to change states.

To check and see what validation errors there are, use:

```
k.valid?
k.errors.each {|field, message| puts "#{field}: #{message}"}
```

and look at the output. Fix those issues and then try state transitions again.